# How can I cover a div with a semi-transparent image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to cover a `<div>` so it looks like it has a semi-transparent block over it.

I am using jQuery but I do not know how to do it.

Any help thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have another `div`, you can just get the dimensions + position like

```
var $somediv = $('#some_div_element'),
    pos      = $.extend({
       width:    $somediv.outerWidth(),
       height:   $somediv.outerHeight()
    }, $somediv.position());
```

and then use it while dynamically creating an overlay

```
$('<div>', {
    id:    'overlay',
    css:   {
        position:         'absolute',
        top:              pos.top,
        left:             pos.left,
        width:            pos.width,
        height:           pos.height,
        backgroundColor:  '#000',
        opacity:          0.50
    }
}).appendTo($somediv);
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/GkFu4/1/

Comment: +1 because I didn't know that the element-ecreating portion of jQuery let you supply properties (esp. CSS) like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS3 to do this. Position a `<div>` absolutely on top of it and give the `<div>` a background of: `rgba(255,255,255,.3)`.

Comment: Is this rgba feature compatible on all platforms? Eg:IE7